# is there a way to just test the ItemProcessor in spring batch

Tags: unit-testing, spring-batch

All of our business logic is coded in the ItemProcessor.   Rather than testing the entire Step that Reads/Processes/Writes records I would like to just invoke the Processor with a given Input record that I create for each test case.

I would control the input data that I feed to it by record creation.  I would expect specific results so I would like to just assert he individual fields in the output record returned.

How could I invoke the Processor bean itself and get result back?

Comment: and why can't it be done with JUnit unit testing? I mean, how is it different than the way we unit test a normal class? Let me know if you are facing any specific challenges in doing that.

Comment: just create your Processor and call process method with proper arguments.
if you need processor as a bean, load spring configuration and inject processor to test case class.